# Remove all many to many relationship items

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to remove all the many to many items from a collection, this code don't fail but the relationed items are not deleted

```
`$foods = $distributorDestiny->getFoods();
$foods->clear();
$distributorDestiny->setFoods($foods);
$em->flush();
```

`

Do I missed something?

I added this function to the entity, but the related itmes are note deleted from the database

```
public function removeFoods():void
    {
        $this->foods->clear();
    }
```

I setted on delete cascade on distributor entity this way

```
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="distributor_food", joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="distributor_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="food_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")})
```

Comment: foreach ($distributorDestiny->getFoods() as $food) {
            $distributorDestiny->removeFood($foor);
        }
        
        $em->flush();  Remove like this and please create add/remove method in your distributorDestiny entity

Comment: I'm trying yo avoid to making  a loop

Comment: public function setFoods(ArrayCollection $collection)
    {
        $this->foods = $collection;
    } add this funciton in entity and use like this $distributorDestiny->setFoods(new ArrayCollection()); and do flush

Comment: I tried but the data is stil on database

Comment: add cascate remove in many to many relational field on distrubutordestiny entity

Comment: I added on delete cascade but the data is stil on the database, (changes are posted on the question)

Comment: @OneToMany(targetEntity="Phonenumber", mappedBy="contact", cascade={"remove"})

Comment: using onDelete="CASCADE" is working but only removing one by one on  a loop, doesnt work replacing the arraycolecction for a new empty arraycollection

Comment: This problem is not big as you can see this is simple to fixed it please read documentation of symfony or see best practices code and than try